# Java MySQL Connector doesn't return table rows correctly with JOIN clause

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use `mysql-connector-java 6.0.5` and tried other versions (tried all with 5.1.*)

```
@Query(value = "select c.* from sub_object c,connectSectionAndSubobject tr where tr.sectionID = 'something'"
        ,nativeQuery = true)
List<SubObjectEntity> findEntity();
```

It works good from MySQL Workbench, but from java code result always is an empty resultSet.
If I take a look at the ResultSet I can see that ResultSet.invalidRowReason = "Illegal operation on empty result set."
But if i try executeQuery like this all works nice:

```
@Query(value = "select c.* from sub_object c,connectSectionAndSubobject tr where tr.objectID = 1"
        ,nativeQuery = true)
```

The table was created by this query:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `connectSectionAndSubobject` (
>     `subobjectID` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `sectionID` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

I tried to change `tr.sectionID = 'something'` to `tr.sectionID LIKE 'something'` but that also failed.
I don't understand how it should work. couldyou help me please?

Comment: Should 'something' be a parameter to your query?

Comment: Yes, of course, but not now, at the first  I want find right way to exequte this  query. Problem is, because the native query don't work as good as in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Colud you provide the table creating script for table `sub_object` ? Maybe some example rows for the two tables, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Another question: have you tried to connect the tables via the query? I mean something like this: `select c.* from sub_object c,connectSectionAndSubobject tr where c.id = tr.subobjectID and tr.objectID = 1`  - Assuming that there is a column called `id` in table sub_object.

Comment: yes, and it`s work on Workbench, and good work from code. But if i try 
compare column by String it didn't work from java code `Illegal operation on empty result set.` result again. It is possible, that maybe java can't compare by String or Char?

Comment: So if I get you right, when you remove the WHERE clause from youre @Query, it works perfectly? Because in this case you only have to give the parameter in the right way: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters

Comment: Or maybe this approach is even better: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: I try do it by all this ways, but if i don't try compare tr.sectionID with String it's work correct and resultSet always has members. By the other way when i try compare with String result set always `Illegal operation on empty result set.`. This is reason why i think, that maybe mysql-connector just can't compare with String when use JOIN, or maybe some other errors. Point is, that all this way use mysql-connector, and all ways give same result

Comment: What type is your column `sectionId` in your database? Is it a number, or a varchar?

Comment: I create it table by 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `section_object` (
  `_id` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your SubObjectEntity class? I try to reproduce your problem.Another question: is the section_object table you mentioned in your previous comment the same as sub_object table?

Comment: The problem was solved by coworker, the mysql-connector use WINDOWS-1252 as a default coding, just was need add `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to url of connection

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by coworker, the mysql-connector use WINDOWS-1252 as a default coding, just was need add

> ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

to url of connection